# Copy row where cell matches worksheet name

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that moves rows to a specific worksheet where a cell value in column M is equal to value: 'not planned'

```
Sub Not_Planned()

Sheets("All Data").Select

RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To RowCount

    Range("M" & i).Select
    check_value = ActiveCell

    If check_value = "not planned" Then
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets("Not Planned").Select
        RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
        Range("a" & RowCount + 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("All Data").Select
        Range("A2").Select
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Is there a way to adapt the code so it runs through all rows and copies the row to a worksheet where the value in column A is equal to a worksheet name ?

Please note: I already have a code that creates worksheets and names them as per unique values in column A.

Thanks

Comment: Will the value in column **A** contain the *full* name like **Book1.xlsm** or just **Book1??**

Comment: worksheet not workbook @Gary'sStudent

Answer (score 1):

Edited... Apparently you [**CAN** use `RowCount` twice and change it mid-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824936/for-start-to-end-loop-with-end-variable-changing-mid-loop).  Not good practice as the variable is being sourced in two different sheets, but it technically will work.

First off [STOP USING `SELECT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Second this should do it (only if you want to move "not planned" items to a different sheet):

```
Sub Not_Planned()

Dim DataSht As Worksheet, DestSht As Worksheet

Set DataSht = Sheets("All Data")

RowCount = DataSht.Cells(Cells.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To RowCount

    check_value = DataSht.Range("M" & i).Value

    If check_value = "not planned" Then
        DataSht.Range("M" & i).EntireRow.Copy
        Set DestSht = Sheets(DataSht.Range("A" & i).Value)
          'You might want some error handling here for if the Sheet doesn't exist!
        DestLast = DestSht.Cells(Cells.Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
        DestSht.Range("a" & DestLast + 1).Paste
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

If you want to run the "planned" after your "not planned" macro then:

```
Sub Planned()

Dim DataSht As Worksheet, DestSht As Worksheet

Set DataSht = Sheets("All Data")

RowCount = DataSht.Cells(Cells.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 to RowCount
        DataSht.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Copy
        Set DestSht = Sheets(DataSht.Range("A" & i).Value)
          'You might want some error handling here for if the Sheet doesn't exist!
        DestLast = DestSht.Cells(Cells.Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
        DestSht.Range("a" & DestLast + 1).Paste
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This version ignores column **M** and uses column **A** instead:

```
Sub Not_Planned()

Sheets("All Data").Select

RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To RowCount
    DestinationSheet = Range("A" & i).Value

        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets(DestinationSheet).Select
        RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
        Range("a" & RowCount + 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("All Data").Select
        Range("A2").Select

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: 1. [STOP USING SELECT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) and 2. he said it needs to check M for "not planned".

Comment: @Gary's Student - I get a 'Substring out of range' error on line 'Sheets(DestinationSheet).Select' ... any ideas ?

Comment: @SMORF.......... This usually means that there is a spelling error somewhere and the variables in column **A** do not exactly match the tabnames.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent ... when I hover over the 'DestinationSheet' it shows me 'CUNR' which is the column A header ... how can I start the code at row 2 and ignore the column header?

Comment: @SMORF `i = 2 to RowCount`

Comment: @Gary'sStudent ... this code duplicates row 2 on each worksheet the same amount of times as the count of each column A value ?