# For start To end Loop with end Variable Changing Mid-Loop

Tags: vba, loops, excel

Starting with test data:

[image: Start]

And running the code:

```
Sub TestLoop()

Dim LastRow As Long, CurRow As Long
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For CurRow = 1 To LastRow
    Range("B" & CurRow).Value = "Done"
    LastRow = 2
Next CurRow

End Sub
```

I would expect the Loop to end at Row 2 because I changed the variable `LastRow`.  However the result is:

[image: Done]

The [MSDN Reference **FOR VB.NET** has this to say](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx):

> When a `For...Next` loop starts, Visual Basic evaluates `start`, `end`, and `step`. Visual Basic evaluates these values only at this time and then assigns `start` to `counter`. Before the statement block runs, Visual Basic compares `counter` to `end`. If `counter` is already larger than the `end` value (or smaller if `step` is negative), the `For loop` ends and control passes to the statement that follows the `Next` statement. Otherwise, the statement block runs.
>
> Each time Visual Basic encounters the `Next` statement, it increments `counter` by `step` and returns to the `For` statement. **Again it compares `counter` to `end`**, and again it either runs the block or exits the loop, depending on the result. This process continues until `counter` passes `end` or an `Exit For` statement is encountered. **[Emphasis mine]**

**Given that it checks the `counter` against the `end` every iteration, shouldn't changing the variable change the `end`?**

Comment: Why not just use Exit For to jump out of the loop early when you need to?

Comment: @KevenDenen The original purpose of this test was to see if you were copying data over from one sheet to another in that new sheet's `LastRow` if you could use the same `LastRow` variable.  My original theory was that changing it mid-loop with actually create an infinite loop: Copy Row 1 in Sheet1 to Row 2 in Sheet 2, `LastRow` becomes 2, `Next` changes `CurRow` to 2 which fits so `Loop` continues.  This would technically create an infinite loop. [But documentation proved otherwise.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27825010/4241535)

Comment: It's typically considered bad practise to alter any of the counters inside of a `For...Next` loop: if you need this type of approach then a `While`-type loop is the preferred approach.

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm talking specifically about `<end-value>` which apparently cannot be changed per the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to note a few things here. First, you're referencing the **VB.Net** documentation. So, I wouldn't rely on that when talking about *VBA*. In fact, the [VBA Documentation for the `For...Next` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251601(v=office.15).aspx) doesn't mention this behavior at all. So, I dug a little deeper and VBA does indeed behave the same as VB.Net here. The following is from the [[MS-VBAL]: VBA Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee157012.aspx).

> The expressions `<start-value>`, `<end-value>`, and `<step-increment>` are evaluated ***once***, in order, and prior to any of the following computations.

This means that `LastRow` in your example is only calculated when first entering the loop. Changing it afterward has no effect on the number of times the loop will run. (Not that I advise trying to do that to begin with.)

This also means that you can not change the size of the steps the loop takes mid-execution as well and this snippet shows the "odd" behavior of both of these at once.

```
Sub TestLoop()

    Dim LastRow As Long, CurRow As Long, StepsToTake As Integer
    LastRow = 100
    StepsToTake = 2

    For CurRow = 1 To LastRow Step StepsToTake
        Range("B" & CurRow).Value = "Done"
        LastRow = 2
        StepsToTake = 1
    Next CurRow

End Sub
```

---

For those interested, here are the entire runtime semantics of the `For...Next` statement.

> **Runtime Semantics.**
>
> - The expressions `<start-value>`, `<end-value>`, and `<step-increment>` are evaluated once, in order, and prior to any of
>     the following computations. If the value of `<start-value>`,
>     `<end-value>`, and `<step-increment>` are not Let-coercible to Double,
>     error 13 (Type mismatch) is raised immediately. Otherwise, proceed
>     with the following algorithm using the original, uncoerced values.
> - Execution of the `<for-statement>` proceeds according to the following algorithm:
>
>   1. If the data value of `<step-increment>` is zero or a positive number, and the value of `<bound-variable-expression>` is greater than
>        the value of `<end-value>`, then execution of the `<forstatement>`
>        immediately completes; otherwise, advance to Step 2.
>   2. If the data value of `<step-increment>` is a negative number, and the value of `<bound-variable-expression>` is less than the value
>        of `<end-value>`, execution of the `<for-statement>` immediately
>        completes; otherwise, advance to Step 3.
>   3. The `<statement-block>` is executed. If a `<nested-for-statement>` is present, it is then executed. Finally, the
>        value of `<bound-variable-expression>` is added to the value of
>        `<step-increment>` and Let-assigned back to
>        `<bound-variable-expression>`. Execution then repeats at step 1.
> - If a `<goto-statement>` defined outside the `<for-statement>` causes a `<statement>` within `<statement-block>` to be executed, the
>     expressions `<start-value>`, `<end-value>`, and `<step-increment>` are
>     not evaluated. If execution of the `<statement-block>` completes and
>     reaches the end of the `<statement-block>` without having evaluated
>     `<start-value>`, `<end-value>` and `<step-increment>` during this
>     execution of the enclosing procedure, an error is generated (number
>     92, "For loop not initialized"). This occurs even if 
>     contains an assignment expression that initializes
>     `<bound-variable-expression>` explicitly. Otherwise, if the
>     expressions `<start-value>`, `<end-value>`, and `<step-increment>`
>     have already been evaluated, the algorithm continues at Step 3
>     according to the rules defined for execution of a `<for-statement>`.
> - When the `<for-statement>` has finished executing, the value of `<bound-variable-expression>` remains at the value it held as of the
>     loop completion.

Answer (score 4):

Given that the [Correct MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee157012.aspx) mentions:

> The expressions `<start-value>`, `<end-value>`, and `<step-increment>` are evaluated once, in order, and prior to any of the following computations.

It appears that Visual Basic **CAN** remember the value of the `end` during the loop even if the variable containing the `end` amount changes.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Chrismas007's answer above, if you want to short-circuit the loop within the confines of the `For` structure, you can just set the incremented variable to the terminating value:

```
For CurRow = 1 To LastRow
    Range("B" & CurRow).Value = "Done"

    ' This will end the loop.
    ' When Next is hit, CurRow will be LastRow + 1.
    CurRow = LastRow

    ' Alternately, you can exit the for loop immediately.
    ' Usually this would be inside an If statement.
    Exit For
Next CurRow
```